# Comparar campo data com data atual no datagridviwer

Tags: c#

Tenho um campo no meu `datagridiviwer` que se chama "PROGRAMAÇÃO" este campo recebe uma data, que vem do banco como varchar ou string, preciso comparar a data que esta neste campo com a data atual, se for maior que a data atual a linha do data `datagridiviwer` muda de cor. Fiz o comando abaixo mas não estou conseguindo o resultado que espero, esta trocando a cor de todas as linhas.

segue meu código

```
else if (row.Cells["PROGRAMAÇÃO"].Value.ToString() != Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now))
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converta o valor da célula para DateTime, e depois faça a comparação:

```
else if (DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["PROGRAMAÇÃO"].Value.ToString()) > DateTime.Now)
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
}
```

Obs. Se a célula estiver em branco, nula, ou com um formato incorreto, irá acontecer erro no Parse. Talvez seja necessário tratar esse problema.

**Edit:** Tratando possíveis erros.

```
if (...)
{ 
    ...
}
else if (row.Cells["PROGRAMAÇÃO"].Value != null)
{
    DateTime programacao; //variavel auxiliar
    if (DateTime.TryParse(row.Cells["PROGRAMAÇÃO"].Value.ToString(), out programacao))
    {
        if (programacao > DateTime.Now)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
    }
}
```

Comment: Realmente Rovann na maioria dos casos este campo fica em branco, como posso tratar isso no meu código, vc poderia me explicar?

Comment: @JuniorGuerreiro alterei o código, veja se ocorre tudo bem

Comment: Rovann eu fiz o teste aqui do jeito que vc me disse antes de alterar o código e não deu erro no parse não, mas vou tentar desta forma que vc me passou também.

Comment: melhor fazer tratando...pq se `.Value` for null, já vai dar de cara um `object not reference to an instance`, e se não for nulo e a string não for uma data, vai dar um `seqüência de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto`

Comment: Testei as duas respostas e as duas funcionaram perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
if (row.Cells["PROGRAMAÇÃO"].Value != null)
{
    DateTime dataProgramacao = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["PROGRAMAÇÃO"].Value.ToString();
    DateTime dataAtual = DateTime.Now;
    int resultado = DateTime.Compare(dataProgramacao, dataAtual);

    if (resultado < 0)
    //dataProgramacao é menor que a dataAtual
    else if (resultado == 0)
     //datas iguais
    else
    //dataProgramacao é maior que a dataAtual
    //row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
}
```

Creio que atende o que deseja.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda...testei e também funcionou sua resposta.